# While moving the enemy left to right, if you change levels he keeps going

Tags: actionscript-3

```
    public function goalieLoop(e:Event):void
    {
        if (goalie!=null)
        {
            if (direction=="right")
            {
                goalie.x+=5;
            }

            else
            {
                goalie.x-=5;
            }     
            if (goalie.x==500 && direction=="right")
            {
                direction="left";
            }
            else if (goalie.x==300 && direction=="left")
            {
                direction="right";
            }

        }
    }
```

This is how I make my enemy move left to right, but once I get to the next level, depending on the way he was going, he keeps going that direction off the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is with your boundary conditions.  It is always better to use `<=` and `>=` instead of `==`.  Also, I don't think you care about the current direction when you check for switching directions.  Regardless if the code thinks it is going left or right and x is more than 500, then you should go left.

```
public function goalieLoop(e:Event):void
{
    if (goalie!=null)
    {
        if (direction=="right")
        {
            goalie.x+=5;
        }

        else
        {
            goalie.x-=5;
        }     
        // change was made here: >= instead of ==
        //   and direction check was removed
        if (goalie.x>=500)
        {
            direction="left";
        }
        // change was made here: <= instead of ==
        //   and direction check was removed
        else if (goalie.x<=300)
        {
            direction="right";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: oh Thank you ! I understand

Answer (score 2):

Before you change scenes, remove the event listener that triggers your goalieLoop and reset your direction variable.